# mvnrepository doesn't show google-api-services-chat library

Tags: java, google-chat

mvnrepository doesn't show google-api-services-chat library

the documentation refers to https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/libraries#java

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-chat:v1-rev20211125-1.32.1'
}
```

but the maven repo shows only an older version, is it a different repo then?

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-chat
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-chat/v1-rev135-1.25.0
```

Comment: That's cause it is the latest in mvnrepos https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a different repo then?

Yes, Maven Central and Maven Repository (mvnrepository.com) are different thing.

Maven Central is the official repository for Apache Maven and is managed by the Apache Software Foundation. Maven Central is the default repository that Maven uses to download dependencies.

mvnrepository.com are indexes the contents of Maven Central and other repositories, and provides additional features such as dependency management tools and user reviews.

You can check the latest version of maven central repository here:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-chat